# MS Access: Link a progress bar to a running Macro

Tags: ms-access, progress-bar

I know this topic has been discussed a lot but maybe there are already some improved solutions...

I want to link a progress bar to my Macro, so the user will se how long he has to wait until the process is finished.

Is there any VBA code to put on the top of the Macro or some way to link the progress bar to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my case...

```
Private Sub Import_Click()

Me!ProgressBar.Visible = True

Form_frmExcelImportWizard.ProgressBar.Min = 0

Form_frmExcelImportWizard.ProgressBar.Max = 100

Command 1
ProgressBar.Value = 1
Command 2
ProgressBar.Value = 2
'...
Command 100
ProgressBar.Value = 100
Me!ProgressBar.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in status toolbar's progress bar. Here is an example: [MSDN: Status Bar Progress Meter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845770.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)